# Database design for 3 tables with one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have three tables

`band`
`member`
`instrument`

Each member can be a member of several bands, but can only play one instrument in each band. I need help with designing the database for this and which relations to use.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  SO is for specific programming and tech questions.

Comment: Good. And what is your own approach, how would you design it? What are your own thoughts about your problem? What did you actually try?

Answer (score 0):

[image: ER Diagram]

Add a new table "BMI", having Composite PK (Using Brand and Member PK Columns) and I_Pk as non primary column of instrument table.